# Adding new users and signing back in to my account?! (Firebase auth)

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have this scenario where I want to register some new users while I am signed in as another user:

- Sign in as user 1
- `reauthenticateWithCredenitals` //*to save the credentials for later sign in*
- Register new user 2
- Log out as user 2
- Sign back in as user 1

**Is this a right approach? Or, should I just write and deploy a function that does this for me?**

Comment: If you just need to create an account, using the Firebase Admin SDK on a backend is a far easier option.

Comment: @DougStevenson does it support React-Native?

Comment: RN is not a backend technology.

Comment: @DougStevenson I meant do I need to install a package for it ? How do I implement that SDK? I dont even have a backend for my app, I just connect directly to Firebase.

Comment: @DougStevenson I think I can only use SDK Admin if I am running a server. I dont have a server. So, back to the question- can I actually do that what I asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you dont have a server to run Firebase Admin SDK, you can use Firebase Cloud Function https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
Then you can register User 2, without signout with the user 1.

To go in detail, with firebase function you can do it in 2 different way:

1) use **onCall** method https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable
It will expose an endpoint, like an API, which you can call with your app
When **onCall** is triggered, you can create you user in firebase Auth

2) use **onCreate** event https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events
in order to listen to you "User" collection.
On the client side you can push a new user (document) in the User collection.
When **onCreate** is triggered, you can create user 2 in firebase Auth

**In both case you can use Firebase Admin SDK in Firebase Cloud Function**

Comment: I also need to get the user ID of the newly created user, can I still do it with one of these two options?

Comment: @bmmf yes you can in both case. As you will use the admin sdk ( you will probably do: admin.auth().createUser( newUserDdata ) ), this function will return the new user. see the example here https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: How about dropping all this out and just using `reauthenticateWithCredenitals`, I mean to make it simple and stay within client-side code?

Comment: I just saw that I need to implement Firebase Admin SDK in my client app. Firebase is just killing me, as soon as I think I am ready to solve something, another thing pops up!

Comment: do I have to implement that SDK in my client in order to make your approach work?

Comment: Admin SDK will only work in Backend (Node.js, python, C#...)

Comment: What I am confused about is, do I need to implement something in my RN app to call the functions in  "Admin Auth API" as you suggested OR I can just call those functions directly from my RN app??

Comment: with react-native-firebase you can call the functions direclty, like that:       firebase.functions().httpsCallable('myNewUserEvent')({ newUser Data})

Comment: I set up the function environment so now I can deploy them. Now, how can I actually retrieve email and password from the client to the function and register new user? Here I have asked the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61180070/how-to-write-a-function-that-accepts-user-email-and-password-from-client-and-reg