# How to write a function that accepts user email and password from client and registers him? (Firestore functions)

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have this case where I want to register users with email and password, so I want to write a function which accepts those two parameters and creates a new user and returns a message OK or something.

**This is my code in React-Native:**

```
  firebase.functions().httpsCallable('registerNewPatient')({
  email: 'testestbmf@hotmail.com',
  password: 'bbbbbb1'
}).then((onfulfilled, onrejected) => {
  if (onfulfilled) {
    console.log("OK callback function:", onfulfilled);
  } else {
    console.log("Error callback function:", onrejected)
  }

}).catch(error => { console.log("ERror handled", error) })
```

**This is the function deployed to Firebase to which I am trying to send email&password, execute and send a response back to RN:**

```
exports.registerNewPatient = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onCall((data, context) => {
const email = context.auth.token.email || null;
const password = context.auth.token.password || null;
const registeredUser = null;
admin.auth().createUser({
    email: email,
    emailVerified: false,
    password: password,
    disabled: false
})
   .then(function (userRecord) {
        registeredUser = userRecord.uid;
    });
return registeredUser;
});
```

Comment: What you have looks like a snippet from the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) showing how to create a user with Admin SDK. Did you already try using that in side your `listProducts` function? What problem did you have when you did that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just updated my code, please take a look of what I have been trying. Btw I did try the example `listProducts` and it worked when I ran it in the console, however, my case is a bit different as I am sending parameters to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to read the email and password from `context.auth`, which is where Cloud Functions passes the current user information from the client to the server. But since you're passing them in as parameters, you need to read them from ``:

```
exports.registerNewPatient = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const email = data.email || null;
    const password = data.password || null;
    ...
```

I'd also get rid of the `|| null` clauses, as it seems your code isn't supposed to work without email and password:

```
exports.registerNewPatient = functions.region('europe-west3').https.onCall((data, context) => {
    if (!data.email) throw "Missing email parameter";
    if (!data.password) throw "Missing password parameter";
    const email = data.email;
    const password = data.password;
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I am having this error: `[Error: NOT_FOUND]`

Comment: So that sounds like the initial problem is gone, so should be a new question. You might want to add some logging to see where the problem comes from, because that message in itself is not very descriptive.

Comment: To be honest thats the only message I am getting!

Comment: Yeah, hence the console logging, both to see how far your code is running before it raises that error, and to log any values that might be relevant to it. In a new question, also be sure to include both the log output and the [minimal, complete client and server code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it helps in trouble shooting.

Comment: please check the newly posted question about this error.